# ImportError when importing from a lower module

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I'm trying to import an object named `db` (SQLAlchemy object) in in a module of my Flask Project in order to use the SQLAlchemy in my models (`models.py`). Assuming my package is named `Foo` and contains the `db` object in his `__init__.py` file , when i try to do a `from Foo import db`, i get the following error:

`ImportError: cannot import name db`

I'm using Flask Blueprint to dispatch my project into two applications (dashboard and frontend) and each of them contains an `__init__.py`file. Only the `models.py` is throwing this error, i got some imports in my views file (as importing the login manager) and everything goes well.

Any idea of what it could be ?

UPDATE : The traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "run.py", line 4, in <module>
        from kuchiyose import app
    File "/path_to_project/kuchiyose/kuchiyose/__init__.py", line 60, in <module>
        from kuchiyose import dashboard, frontend
    File "/path_to_project/kuchiyose/kuchiyose/dashboard/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
        from dashboard import views
    File "/path_to_project/kuchiyose/kuchiyose/dashboard/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
        from dashboard import views
    File "/path_to_project/kuchiyose/kuchiyose/dashboard/views.py", line 8, in <module>
        from kuchiyose.dashboard.models import User
    File "/path_to_project/kuchiyose/kuchiyose/dashboard/models.py", line 3, in <module>
        from kuchiyose import db

ImportError: cannot import name db
```

Comment: object or class `db`?

Comment: It's an instance of the SQLAlchemy class. That's why i said object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, thanks for the help. Concerning my second question : "How to import Flask models into views without having a circular import issue (when using SQLAlchemy)", i found a solution. It consists to setup the SQLAlchemy object not into the application `__init__.py`file but into the `models.py`file itself. With that, you can import it in your `views.py`file without problem.

My models.py file, now:

```
from kuchiyose import app
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

And my views.py

```
from kuchiyose.dashboard import models
```

Answer (score 6):

This is an old one but showed up as a top result in my search.

I have a project that has model declarations in a few different places rather than a consolidated models.py file so this solution wouldn't be ideal. I found importing your views AFTER establishing the db object works as well.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# Now Register routes
# db is now defined so app import db will now work)
from routes.user import user as user_routes
app.register_blueprint(user_routes)
```

Answer (score 4):

there appears to be circular imports:

- `kuchiyose/__init__.py` imports from `kuchiyose.dashboard.views`
- `kuchiyose/dashboard/views.py` imports from `kuchiyose.dashboard.models`
- `kuchiyose/dashboard/models.py` imports from `kuchiyose`

see e.g. [Circular (or cyclic) imports in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/744373/1176601) for more info...

Comment: Thanks for the help, it really helped (i had an `import views` that was raising a Circular import). But, that's view import was serving to load my application views. So, do you have any idea about how i can do that now ? (if you are a Flask developer)